# Will pooping in a flowerpot before planting ivy help it grow?

Tags: houseplants, container-gardening, urban-gardening

I have heard poop can actually be really good fertilizer. Truth be told, in my county, the solid waste division takes figure remains and uses it as fertilizer that is sold for planting.

With this in mind, what would happen if I took some soil, put it in a flowerpot and then pooped on it, and then covered that with more soil? Would this be a good fertilizer and help a plant grow? I'm not joking at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really wouldn't advise it - human faecal waste is processed and used as fertilizer even in the UK, although most of it is used by the agricultural industry. But its the 'processed' part that counts. The treatment process produces biosolids which are 99.99% free of pathogens, because human faecal matter can contain a startling array of really quite nasty and infectious pathogens. Given you are talking about doing what you're doing for a plant that will be kept in the house, it's even more of a bad idea, not least from the odour point of view.  There are one or two areas of the world where raw human waste is used, but usually because there's nothing else at all available and it's used outdoors, usually on crops. The risk from pathogens within it are primarily to humans rather than the plants.

If all you're growing is Ivy, that's as tough as old boots and needs no special treatment nor fertilisers to help it grow anyway, though it will  need watering.